# hz of our sensor's the topic was DECREASED, When I record some data with rosbag

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic, rosbag-record, camera, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, experts.
I used rosbag to acquire our sensor data as camera, lidar.
You can reference below spec.

Camera Node : 1980x1208 (FHD, RGB), 20 hz
Lidar Node : 64 Channel, 20 hz

I recorded topics on pc using rosbag, but there is a decreasing.
// command `$ rosbag record camera_topoic lidar_points_topic`
When I check on another pc, their spec are blew.

Camera Node: 20 hz -> 5~6 hz
Lidar Node: 20 hz -> 8~10 hz

I don't know where it depend on which problem.
How can I debug this problem?
Is there a general information which is good for this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300529/hz-of-our-sensor%27s-the-topic-was-decreased,-when-i-record-some-data-with-rosbag./) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're maxing out any of the resources of your computer then you would expect the message rate to decrease when you add more load on top. Have you tried running [rqt_top](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_top) to measure how much CPU and memory each of your nodes are using?

If you are indeed maxing out your computer you could try recording the rosbag on another computer or connecting the sensors to two different computers to spread the load. Although in this case you want to be careful you don't max out your network bandwidth.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2018-08-20**:
Hello, @PeteBlackerThe3rd .
Thanks for your answer.

The problem was the network bandwidth.
`rqt_top` is a very useful package for me.
Thanks again.